# How do I substitute values in DF1 using values from DF2 if certain conditions are not met in DF1?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have the following dput which produces DF1

```
structure(list(ID = c("ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", 
"ID_1"
), Book = c("Book_A", "Book_A", "Book_B", "Book_B", "Book_C", "Book_C", "Book_D", "Book_D", 
"Book_E", "Book_E"), OU = c("Over", "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", 
"Under", "Over", "Under"), Price = c(102, -114, 100, -120, 102, -113, -102, -119, -120, 105), 
Points = c(6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = 
c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

DF1 tibble

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
ID    Book   OU    Price Points
<chr> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 ID_1  Book_A Over    102    6.5
2 ID_1  Book_A Under  -114    6.5
3 ID_1  Book_B Over    100    6.5
4 ID_1  Book_B Under  -120    6.5
5 ID_1  Book_C Over    102    6.5
6 ID_1  Book_C Under  -113    6.5
7 ID_1  Book_D Over   -102    6.5
8 ID_1  Book_D Under  -119    6.5
9 ID_1  Book_E Over   -120    6  
10 ID_1  Book_E Under   105    6
```

and I have the following dput with produces DF2

```
structure(list(ID = c("ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", "ID_1", 
"ID_1"
), Book = c("Book_E", "Book_E", "Book_E", "Book_E", "Book_E", "Book_E", "Book_E", "Book_E", 
"Book_E", "Book_E"), 
OU = c("Over", "Over", "Over", "Over", "Over", "Under", "Under", 
   "Under", "Under", "Under"), Price = c(-303, -150, 107, 176, 372, 261, 133, -120, -200, 
-447), Points = c(5, 5.5, 6.5, 7, 8.5, 5, 5.5, 6.5, 7, 8.5)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = 
c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

DF2 tibble

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
ID    Book   OU    Price Points
<chr> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 ID_1  Book_E Over   -303    5  
2 ID_1  Book_E Over   -150    5.5
3 ID_1  Book_E Over    107    6.5
4 ID_1  Book_E Over    176    7  
5 ID_1  Book_E Over    372    8.5
6 ID_1  Book_E Under   261    5  
7 ID_1  Book_E Under   133    5.5
8 ID_1  Book_E Under  -120    6.5
9 ID_1  Book_E Under  -200    7  
10 ID_1  Book_E Under  -447    8.5
```

As you can see, the Points values in Rows 9 and 10 (Value of 6) of DF1 do not match the other Points values for Rows 1 - 8 (Value of 6.5).  What I would like to do is replace the Price AND Points values for Row 9 and 10 with the corresponding Price and Points values in DF2 if the Points values don't match.  This is the desired output which we will call DF3.

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
ID    Book   OU    Price Points
<chr> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 ID_1  Book_A Over    102    6.5
2 ID_1  Book_A Under  -114    6.5
3 ID_1  Book_B Over    100    6.5
4 ID_1  Book_B Under  -120    6.5
5 ID_1  Book_C Over    102    6.5
6 ID_1  Book_C Under  -113    6.5
7 ID_1  Book_D Over   -102    6.5
8 ID_1  Book_D Under  -119    6.5
9 ID_1  Book_E Over    107    6.5  
10 ID_1  Book_E Under  -120   6.5
```

This is not static data and each time I make a call to an API, the contents of DF1 and DF2 will change.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What if there are more than 2 unique values and they have the same frequency in DF1

Comment: This is a legitimate question Akrun.  I haven't encountered this issue yet but it may very well surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Mode()` function provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/17303805), change `Price` to `NA` where `Points` doesn’t match the modal value. Then set `Points` to the modal value, then update the missing values of `Price` using `rows_patch()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

df1 %>%
  mutate(
    Price = ifelse(Points == Mode(Points), Price, NA),
    Points = Mode(Points)
  ) %>%
  rows_patch(
    df2, 
    by = c("ID", "Book", "OU", "Points"),
    unmatched = "ignore"
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   ID    Book   OU    Price Points
   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ID_1  Book_A Over    102    6.5
 2 ID_1  Book_A Under  -114    6.5
 3 ID_1  Book_B Over    100    6.5
 4 ID_1  Book_B Under  -120    6.5
 5 ID_1  Book_C Over    102    6.5
 6 ID_1  Book_C Under  -113    6.5
 7 ID_1  Book_D Over   -102    6.5
 8 ID_1  Book_D Under  -119    6.5
 9 ID_1  Book_E Over    107    6.5
10 ID_1  Book_E Under  -120    6.5
```